# console emoji/unicode support broken on my eoan installation

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, fonts, emoji

My installation went from Gnome to Lubuntu via installation of `lubuntu-desktop` and subsequent removal of the gnome packages, so it is a bit nonstandard.

Somewhere in between, the emoji support for the console broke, and I would like to know how to fix it (installation is otherwise fine). The existing answers on AskUbuntu don't apply or don't solve the issue.

The issue: When I execute `curl v2.wttr.in/Berlin` in the terminal, I expect to see an extensive weather report with proper symbols (rain clouds etc), but on this computer, most of them are just the 'tofu' boxes indicating that a symbol wasn't found.

This is how it is supposed to look like: [image]

And this is how it really looks like: [image]

Notice the difference with the symbols for 'rain' and 'partly cloudy'. How can I get the full emoji range back?

`fonts-noto-color-emoji` is installed, I also ran `fc-cache -f -v`.

Comment: Have you tried gnome-terminal? (just to localize the problem)

Comment: I tried on several terminals, Konsole, qterminal, and also xterm as the standard one. They all show the same behaviour.

Comment: I suppose that your cairo library is too old